# Trying to get a drop-down menu to "drop-up"

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
 background: url('nature.jpg') no-repeat;
 background-size: none;
 margin-left: 10%;
}

ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 font-family: arial;
}

ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: .8;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 7800px;
 bottom: 100%;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
 background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
}
body {
  background-image:url("hintergrundbild.png"),url("hg2.jpg");
  background-attachment: scroll,fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat,no-repeat;
}
html body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>
      Motorräder
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li id="navi1"><a href="index.html">Motorradarten</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Chopper</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Supersportler</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Naked Bike</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Tourer</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Enduro</a></li>
      </ul></li>
      <li id="navi2"><a href="kontakt.html">Motorradmarken</a></li>
      <li id="navi3"><a href="kontakt.html">Gefahren & Sicherheit</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello guys,
I am trying to make a website with an "drop-up" menu.
The drop-down is working but I cant get it to got upwards.
The Background image kind of works like an intro, that's why the drop-down menu is that far down.
I also want the background to change when I hover over the different menu-points, is that possible?
I hope you guys can help me and if so
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I can't see any dropdown ?

Comment: try using negative margins

Comment: The dropdown is really buggy, as it tries to drop under the edge, but it works for sure when it is on the top of the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make use of **`transform: translateY(-100%);`** to the dropdown

```css
body {
  background: url('nature.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: none;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 700px;
  bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 160px;
  display: none;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

body {
  background-image: url("hintergrundbild.png"), url("hg2.jpg");
  background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

html body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>
    Motorräder
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li id="navi1"><a href="index.html">Motorradarten</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Chopper</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Supersportler</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Naked Bike</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Tourer</a></li>
        <li id="typen"><a href="kontakt.html">Enduro</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="navi2"><a href="kontakt.html">Motorradmarken</a></li>
    <li id="navi3"><a href="kontakt.html">Gefahren & Sicherheit</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this will help you!